# Why showing error undefined when using alias defined values in laravel application through VS code php intelephense extension?

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, alias, intelephense

In `config/app.php`

```
'aliases' => [
    'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
],
```

when I am using `Route` in `routes/web.php` like

```
Route::get('/', 'UserController@home');
```

I installed **php intelephense** extension in my **vs code**. So that it is showing error like

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue? (Functionality is working fine but it is showing like the error is the problem)

Comment: Do you have ```use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;``` at the top of your ```web.php```?

Comment: @Andrew If that added in alias then no need to import in a particular file. That's the advantage of using an alias.

Comment: I understand how they work and I am not suggesting that you should have that line included. Whether or not you have it included helps me understand the source of the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aliases are registered at runtime so they are not in the namespace and Intelephense cannot pick them up.

See the question asked on the Intelephense project in Github https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/1116

"These classes don't exist in the workspace. Laravel creates them at runtime. As such they are reported as undefined. The solution is to either provide stub definitions https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper or turn off the diagnostics (intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedTypes)."